# Reordering objects with order property

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Consider objects with an `order` property. Objects will be sorted based on this property.

How would you assign the `order` property given the following restrictions and operations?

**Operations (in order of importance)**

`push(object)`: Insert object at index 0.

`swap(indexN, indexM)`: Swap object at index N with object at index M.

`remove(object)`: Remove object. Remaining elements must retain the same order.

`insert(object)`: Insert object with given order.

**Restrictions**

Changing the `order` property of an object is expensive. Changes should be minimised.

`order` can be integral or floating point, as required by the implementation.

If `order` is kept unique, then operation `insert` must include a way to fix the `order` if it already exists, making as few changes as possible. It can be assumed that if an inserted object has the same `order` than an existing object, there is another criteria to determine which one goes first.

If `order` allows duplicates, then operation `swap` must include a way to fix the `order` of the swapped elements if they have the same value, again making as few changes as possible. Penalising operation `insert` is preferred.

Most likely this problem has a name and a known solution already but I couldn't find it at first glance.

Comment: could you provide a sample use case? might help understand where you're coming from better.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It's for a list of digital objects that can be manually ordered and can be edited in many devices simultaneously. Thus, it is possible for objects to be added in different devices with the same order. Synching has to deal with this case.

Comment: hmm ok. how do you want to handle incompatible orderings, e.g. one device has A,B,C,D, the other has it as D,C,B,A, what do you do when you sync?

Comment: It would leave that out of the scope of the question. I prefer to focus on the four primitives push, swap, remove and insert.

Comment: I don't understand. You can turn ABCD into DCBA via just swapping. what is the user allowed to do and what isn't he?

Comment: I would like to abstract the synching part out of the problem. In any case, yes the user is allowed to do that. But since swapping is just changing the order value, the last order would win when synching. Potentially, you could end with objects with the same order value, but you would deal with those with the same policy that you apply in the insert or swap primitive. That's why I don't think it's necessary to add a synch operation to the original question.

Comment: Ok think I got you, will think about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use floating point for order

For `push`, assign the object an order equal to the order of the object that's now at index 1, minus 1 (`list[0].order = list[1].order - 1`)

For `swap`, swap the two objects' orders (`temp = list[i]; list[i] = list[j]; list[j] = list[i]; temp = list[i].order; list[i].order = list[j].order; list[j].order = temp`); if this might introduce consistency problems then ideally you could put a `transit` flag on the elements to indicate that their order is in the process of being modified, or worst case lock the objects until they're consistent

For `remove`, do nothing - the objects in the list are still ordered, you've just introduced a gap in the sequence which shouldn't be a problem

`insert` is the only problematic one.  If you're inserting an element at index `i`, then its order is equal to the average of the orders of the elements at indices `i-1` and `i+1` (`list[i].order = (list[i-1].order + list[i+1].order)/2`).  Verify that this new order doesn't equal the order at index `i-1` or `i+1` (`list[i].order != list[i-1].order && list[i].order != list[i+1].order`) - this would indicate that you've hit machine epsilon.  When this occurs (and this should rarely if ever occur) you've got two options:

1. Bite the bullet and reorder your entire list, i.e. assign an order of `0` at index 0, an order `1` at index 1, ... an order `n` at index n.
2. Do a local reorder to try to minimize the cost.  Reorder the adjacent elements to `list[i-1].order = (list[i-2].order + list[i-1].order)/2` and `list[i+1].order = (list[i+2].order + list[i+1].order)/2` before reordering `list[i] = (list[i-1] + list[i+1])/2`, again verifying that you haven't reached machine episilon at your [i-1] and [i+1] reordering - if you have reached machine epsilon at e.g. [i-1], then first reorder [i-2] to `list[i-2].order = (list[i-3].order + list[i-2].order)/2`, and then reorder [i-1].  If the [i-2] reorder hits machine epsilon then first reorder [i-3], and so on.  (If you reach the end of the list then simply decrement the order of element [0] or increment the order of element [n].)  As you can see, in the worst case you've got a cascade reordering that is more expensive than had you simply bit the bullet and reordered the entire list; however, in all likelihood the reordering will remain local.  A good compromise is that if you've cascaded too many times (for a reasonable value of "too many") then do a complete reordering.

Comment: +1 Thanks for a the detailed answer Zim-Zam. I think you meant `push` instead of the first `insert`. Also, `insert` is not given an index but an order, so your solution would require searching the whole list to find the index in which it would fit, then replacing its order with the middle of its adjacent objects and then dealing with machine epsilon. Which is fine. Finally, would you use zero or max float as your initial order value? Which one is least likely to produce machine epsilon hits?

Comment: @hpique To help avoid machine epsilon hits, decrement by a value greater than 1 in the `push` operation, e.g. `decrementVal = 2^10; list[0].order = list[1].order - decrementVal`, then to reduce the likelihood that you'll reach `MIN_FLOAT` during a `push` your initial order value should be something like `MAX_FLOAT - decrementVal^2` - by subtracting `decrementVal^2` you simplify the corner case of inserting at the end of the list, allowing you to increment the order of the last list element by `decrementVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw it out there, a doubly linked list gives you:

- `push(object)`: O(1), give it order 1 less than the current head.
- `swap(indexN, indexM)`: O(n), swap the orders
- `remove(object)`: O(1), don't touch any orders
- `insert(object)`: O(n), insert the order so the list is sorted in terms of order

Might not be good since the 2nd most important one has an expensive (change order) operation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `remove` will be O(n) since you need to *find* the node to remove first.

Comment: @Dukeling: when you load the objects up, construct a doubly-linked list, associating each object in the list with the fwd + back pointers. so now you have it instantly with just one `O(n)` at load-time