# Incrementing or decrementing a float

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, floating-point

What is the **minimum** value `d` such that...

```
f - d != f
f + d != f
```

...for any `CGFloat` `f` (except infinity)?

For example, it's not `1`.

```
CGFloat f = CGFLOAT_MAX;
CGFloat d = 1;
NSLog(@"%d", f - d != f); // Prints 0
```

Comment: My floating point arithmetic is a bit rusty. Apologies.

Comment: What Are You Really Trying To Do™?

Comment: @StephenCanon Given a float, get the next/previous one. Or at least something good enough.

Comment: @hpique: To get the next/previous float, use `nexttoward(x, INFINITY)` or `nexttoward(x, -INFINITY)` (for `double`, `nexttowardf` for `float`). Test the preprocessor identifier `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` to know whether `CGFLOAT` is `float` or `double`.

Comment: If your floating-point arithmetic is rusty, you should probably take care in computations that require calculating the next or previous representable value of a `CGFLOAT`. What are you really trying to do? (Not capitalized so I do not have to pay trademark royalties.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's great! The reason I asked for the delta is because I want the Nth next/previous float (or something close), so I was planning on doing `f+delta*n`. I guess I can use the functions you suggested in a loop.

Comment: That raises the question of why you want `delta` steps. Seriously, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wouldn't want to derail the question with the specifics. It's related to using floats for custom orderings, as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793666/143378

Comment: @hpique: That problem does not look like it should involve the use of calculating individual floating-point steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If “any `CGFLOAT`” truly means any value that a `CGFLOAT` can take, then the answer is infinity. Otherwise, `f` could be infinity (a legal value), and `f-d` would equal `f` for any finite value of `d`.

If `f` is limited to finite values, then `d` is 2<sup>970</sup> if `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` is set and 2<sup>103</sup> otherwise. This is because those are the smallest values required to cause a change when `d` is added to the largest finite values that a `CGFLOAT` could have.

These are undoubtedly not the values you are looking for. As Stephen Canon notes, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know infinity was a valid CGFloat (what is the constant, BTW?). No, excluding infinity. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I am just curious: How did you calculate those values? And what do you mean by *adding* a number to the largest possible value? The result would then be infinity?

Comment: @MartinR: Adding a value to the largest possible means, in this context, perform the IEEE-754 operation for addition. Basically, that takes two values *x* and *y*, computes their mathematical sum, *x* + *y*, and rounds the mathematical sum to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format.

Comment: @MartinR: To calculate the value for `d`, I recognized that the largest possible `double` is 2**1024 - 2**(1024-53), then consider what must be added that to cause it to round to a larger value. The ULP (distance between representable values) at this point is 2**(1024-53), so adding that certainly changes the value. Adding half of that produces a mathematical sum that is not representable, but, when it is rounded, it produces a new value. At the upper boundary of the finite values, rounding is performed as if the exponent range continued, rather than going to infinity. Thus,…

Comment: … when we add 1/2 ULP to the largest finite value, we have a value that would round up to the next exponent, if one were available. It is not, so the result is infinity. At this magnitude, 1/2 ULP is 2**(1024-53-1) = 2**970. Additionally, consider what happens if we add a number slightly smaller than 2**970 to the largest value. The result is 2**(1024-53) plus something less than half an ULP. In that case, the result rounds down (I have assumed the usual round-to-nearest mode). Therefore, 2**970 is the smallest value that suffices.

Comment: OK, thanks. So if I understand it correctly, adding your number `d` to `DBL_MAX` would give infinity. - I just wondered about the large number. I had computed `DBL_MAX - nexttoward(DBL_MAX, 0.)` to stay within the range of finite numbers, and that gives 1.99584030953472E+292.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, that calculation gives the ULP of `DBL_MAX`, which is the step size between adjacent values. But, since you only need to go half a step to cause an addition to change the value, that is twice the size needed. (One caveat: Round-to-nearest moves ties toward the even value. So to go from xxx…01 to xxx…10, you only need half an ULP. To go from xxx…00 to xxx…01, you would need slightly more than half an ULP, to avoid the tie.)

Answer (score 0):

The value such that

```
f - d != f
f + d != f
```

is not fixed for all possible floating point numbers. You've probably came to this conclusion your own because you can clearly see that for d=1 and f=5.0, f-d=4.0... but this doesn' work for CGFLOAT_MAX.

This is because of how floating point numbers are stored in memory, they are stored with a base and an exponent, so not all digits are being represented.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the the definition of CGFLOAT on your platform.

Current platforms use either float (typically when compiling for 32-bit platforms) or double (typically when compiling for 64-bit platforms).

32 bit floats use 23 bits for the fraction, which means that `d` would probably be around  `CGFLOAT_MAX/2^23`

64 bit doubles use 52 bits for the fraction, which means that `d` would probably be around  `CGFLOAT_MAX/2^52`

Comment: These are off by “one”; the actual value of `d` would be the next greater representable value.

Comment: I know, that's why I said "around". (If it would be the value or the next representable value would depend on the rounding in the division). I love your answer, btw, it is so to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum value for `d` depends on the value of `f`.

The problem is that `CGFloat` only supports a certain number of significant digits and not all floating point number are represented exactly.

The following is not exact results but meant to illustrate the problem.

If `f` is `1.0` then `d` might need to be something like `0.0000001`. But if `f` is `1000000.0` (one million) then `d` would need to be `0.1`.

Basically the value of `d` must be within the significant digits of `f` for the result to be noticeable.

Consider using `NSDecimalNumber` to be able to fully represent large numbers eliminating this problem.